# how to use directive inside a function for google location

Tags: angularjs, google-maps

i'm trying to use google map directive in my angularjs project heres the directive:

```
.directive("myMaps", function(){
return{
    restrict:'E', //Element Type
    template:'<div></div>', //Defining myApp div
    replace:true, //Allowing replacing

    link: function($scope, element, attributes){

        $scope.title = attributes.title;
        $scope.type = attributes.type;
        alert('fdfd');
        alert($scope.title +'ddddddd'+$scope.type);


        //Initializing Coordinates
        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng($scope.title,$scope.type); 
        var mapOptions = {
            center: myLatLng, //Center of our map based on LatLong Coordinates
            zoom: 5, //How much we want to initialize our zoom in the map
            //Map type, you can check them in APIs documentation
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 
            };

        //Attaching our features & options to the map
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(attributes.id),
                      mapOptions);
        //Putting a marker on the center
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
            title:"My town"
        });
        marker.setMap(map); //Setting the marker up
    }   
};
})
```

it works good, but how i can call it inside a function to take new longitude and altitude??

Comment: show function code from which you call this directive.

Comment: thanks for your answer..this is My question actually...i have no idea how to use it inside a function

Comment: you cant call directive from function... be specific what you want to do?

Comment: i have no idea how to use this directive to take new logitude and altitude if its not possible..is there another way to use this directive to  take new logitude and altitude...??